# emoji module names are not working in python3

Tags: python-3.x, emoji

I'm trying to use some emojis like these:

☺️






























☹️






























...

in python 3.

I have read some docs, and they said I can import "emoji" and use emoji module names and I found website that has a lot of module names. this is the link:

https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/

but none of them worked! (emoji installed by pip3)

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import emoji
>>> print(emoji.emojize(':joy:'))
:joy:
>>> print(emoji.emojize(':joy:'))
:joy:
>>> print(emoji.emojize(':laughing:'))
:laughing:
>>> print(emoji.emojize(':smile:'))
:smile:
```

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

python3

Comment: What happens if you try `print("\U0001f600")`? Edit: I think you can also use `print("\N{grinning face}")`?

Comment: `print(emoji.emojize(':joy:', use_aliases=True))` should work. See the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) for details.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to Unix/Linux, but is not of sufficient quality to consider migrating.

Answer (score 0):

The webfx doesn't seem to work anymore. I'm not sure why either. The emoji names seem to be following the [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/) names instead with the spaces replaced with the underscore. A way that you could check is to use `print(emoji.demojize(''))`

That should return the emoji's name